# Insert current timestamp from groovy to db2

Tags: sql, groovy, db2

DB2 has CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function that returns current timestamp in this format: 2022-05-24-11:22:13.022543

Is there equivalent to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in groovy? How to store current timestamp from groovy to DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Timestamp `import java.sql.Timestamp;` Also set your database column as Timestamp.

```
stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Comment: The only issue here that timestamp precision constructed in this way is limited to milliseconds when in question I see microseconds.